# website can not be found if typing www. before URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, web

not sure if this question fits in with this part of stackover flow but i think it could be a .htaccess issue.

My website can be found when going website.com but not www.website.com

And example is [website link with www](http://www.removedlink.com)

All i have in my htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^viewbuild/([^/.]+)/?$ viewbuild.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^following following.php [L]
RewriteRule ^trending trending.php [L]
RewriteRule ^mybuilds mybuilds.php [L]
RewriteRule ^newlyupdated newlyupdated.php [L]
```

Any ideas on this? The website is being hosted by a friend on a dedi so can ask him to change certain things if he needs to his side.

Thanks. Craig.

Comment: It's a DNS lookup failure, it can't be a `.htaccess` problem.

Comment: `www.buildsanctuary.com` is not a valid domain.

Comment: hmm, the site at buildsanctuary.com works fine. I shall get in touch with the person behind the hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS for `www.buildsanctuary.com` is not correctly configured:

```
➜  ~  nslookup www.buildsanctuary.com
Server:     10.0.0.1
Address:    10.0.0.1#53

** server can't find www.buildsanctuary.com: NXDOMAIN
```

You should add a CNAME entry that redirects queries from `www.buildsanctuary.com` to `buildsanctuary.com`

```
buildsanctuary.com.        CNAME  www.buildsanctuary.com.
```

Comment: thanks for the info, passed it on to the server owner and he just forgot a CNAME when setting everthing up